# Trigger Google map info window with URL hash

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I currently have a Google Map with multiple markers, I'm trying to use the URL to trigger the required marker to display it's info window.

E.G if the URL was **'/index.html#1'** the first marker would open its info window and if **'/index.html#2'** the second marker would open its info window.

I was advised to use **google.maps.event.trigger(markers[urlhash], 'click');** but this doesn't seem to trigger the info window?

Any and all advice would be appreciated, thank you.

**Get URL (/index.html#1):**

```
var urlhash = window.location.hash.replace('#','');
```

**Google Map:**

```
/* Google Map */
function googleMap(){
  var locations = [
    ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
    ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
    ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
    ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
    ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
  ];
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var marker, i;
  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      };
    })(marker, i));
  }

  if(urlhash){
    google.maps.event.trigger(markers[urlhash], 'click');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* Google Map */
function googleMap(){
  var locations = [
    ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
    ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
    ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
    ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
    ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
  ];
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var marker, i;
  var markers = [];
  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      map: map
    });
    markers.push(marker);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      };
    })(marker, i));
  }

  if(urlhash){
    google.maps.event.trigger(markers[urlhash], 'click');
  }

}
```