# Trigger Google map info window with URL hash name

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to trigger the marker info by url hash 'name'.
Instead of a number.
Similar post: [Trigger Google map info window with URL hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37211801/trigger-google-map-info-window-with-url-hash/)

```
var urlhash = window.location.hash.replace('#','');
```

I use this way to place the markers:

```
/* Google Map */
function googleMap(){
 var locations = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
 ];
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 10,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 });
 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
 var marker, i;
 var markers = [];
 for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
   map: map
  });
  markers.push(marker);
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
   return function() {
    map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
    infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
   };
  })(marker, i));
 }

 if(urlhash){
  google.maps.event.trigger(markers[urlhash], 'click');
 }

}
```

For example /index.html#bondi-beach instead of For example /index.html#1
Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the #hash as the index to the array/hashmap:

```
markers[(locations[i][0]).toLowerCase()] = marker;
```

then:

```
if(urlhash){
 google.maps.event.trigger(markers[urlhash.toLowerCase()], 'click');
}
```

[proof of concept](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_hash_20171125.html#bondi%20beach)

**code snippet:**

```js
var urlhash = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');
// for code snippet only
urlhash = "bondi%20beach";
//  ===================
var markers = [];
/* Google Map */
function googleMap() {
  console.log(urlhash);
  var locations = [
    ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
    ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
    ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
    ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
    ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
  ];
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var marker, i;
  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      map: map
    });
    markers[(locations[i][0]).toLowerCase()] = marker;
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      };
    })(marker, i));
  }

  if (urlhash) {
    google.maps.event.trigger(markers[decodeURI(urlhash.toLowerCase())], 'click');
  }

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", googleMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places&ext=.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```